# My Galaxy Nexus detects wifi signal(at home) but can't connect to it

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-nexus

My Galaxy Nexus detects wifi signal(at home) but can't connect to it.

I cant connect to wifi. The wifi icon doesnt appear beside the time on the upper right of the screen. When I try to access facebook it says connection lost. But wifi works properly well on the laptop.

I've switched the ON/OFF , restarted the galaxy Nexus and still nothing.

Please help.

Comment: In Setting => WLAN, what do you see when you tap on the WLAN you want to connect to? Signal, security, advanced options?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I followed tried all of the things you mentioned, but the result is the same. This just started happening. Occasionally, I get an intermittent connect, but most of the time I get that immeidate "Failure to connect to network" message. I have tried a couple different Wi-Fi apps, too.

Answer (score 3):

A few things to try:

- Ensure that the Wi-Fi network you are connecting to is an infrastructure mode (router) and not ad-hoc (shared connection via another phone or laptop) as Android doesn't support ad-hoc mode out of the box.
- Disable the `Avoid poor connections` option under Settings -> Wi-Fi -> Menu -> Advanced.
- On the same screen, switch the `W-Fi frequency band` from default "Auto" option to the one your router uses (2.4 GHz Vs. 5 GHz).
- Check your router settings to ensure it's not filtering by MAC address.  If it is - either disable that option, or add your phone's MAC address to the list of allowed devices.
- Check the settings on the Wifi network on the Settings -> Wi-Fi screen.  Long-press on the network you are trying to connect to, select `Modify network`, and check that the settings for Security are correct.
- Try re-connecting fresh.  On the Settings -> Wi-Fi screen long-press the network you are trying to connect to and select `Forget network` option.  Try re-connecting to it.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and then remembered that the new router was set to only accept connections by MAC address.  When I added my Nexus one MAC address to the new router, it connected perfectly.